# Does a pair of odd cube-free integers satisfying some complicated conditions on their prime divisors exist?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For a positive integer $n$, let $\Pi(n)$ denote the set of prime divisors of $n$, and let $\Pi_2(n)$ denote the set of primes $p$ such that $p^2$ divides $n$. We use $\phi$ to denote Euler's totient function, and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the greatest common divisor function. For a prime $q$, let $A_q(n) = \{p\in\Pi(n) : p\equiv 1\pmod{q}\}$, $B_q(n) = \{p\in\Pi_2(n) : p\equiv -1\pmod{q}\}$ and, for any $n$, define $C(n) = \{ (p,q)\in\Pi(n)\times\Pi_2(n) : q\equiv 1\pmod{p}\}$.

Is there a pair of *odd* cube-free integers $a>1$ and $b>1$ satisfying the following conditions?

- $a$ is *not* square-free;
- for all $q\in\Pi(a)$, we have $\left|A_q(a) \cup B_q(a)\right|\leq 1$;
- $C(a) = \emptyset$;
- $(a,b)=1$;
- $(\phi(a),b)=1$;
- $(a,\phi(b))=1$;
- $(\prod_{p\in\Pi_2(a)}p+1, b)=1.$

(For clarity, the last four conditions assert that the indicated numbers are relatively prime.)

This is a fairly messy set of conditions that arises as a sub-case in counting certain groups of cube-free order.  (The conditions are designed to ensure that a group of order $ab$ has a cyclic group of order $a$ as a direct factor and that there are no other groups of order $a$.) I am wondering whether this case can even occur; I was unable to find any example of such a pair of numbers up to $a,b <10^6$ (assuming I didn't make an error in my computer search).  Perhaps there is some simple number-theoretic reason no such pair can exist?

Comment: For your second bullet point, by $A_p(q)+B_q(a)$ do you mean $A_p(a) \cup B_q(a)$? If not, what do you mean by $+$ here?

Comment: @MatthewConroy Yes, you are right. I've fixed it. Thank you!